# How to reflect the css or js changes on web page without clearing browser cache?

Tags: jquery

I'm  having 1 page jquery based web application, when any changes are done in the css or js of the page, user needs to clear the browser cache to see the reflection of the changes done. Is there a way to reflect the changes on web page  without clearing the browser cache if the user upgrades the web page for the first time.

Comment: What are you using to serve up that page?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to prevent caching, you have to send the following headers to the client:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

You can see how to do that on different platforms on this page: http://dontcache.me/hackers.html

Answer (score 0):

Change cache control in .htaccess file

Comment: If a user is visiting for first time, they will view an up to date version, your question seems a little off, in that I don't know what "upgrades the web page for the first time" means.

Comment: I need to clear the cache only once if any upgrade is done in css or js but on changing the cache control in .htaccess file as suggested above, this would clear the cache everytime, pls suggest.....

Comment: i need it for existing user who is already referring my web page but if any css or js changes are done, he should be able to see the changes without clearing the cache (ctrl+F5).

Answer (score 0):

Are these users within your company or are these public web visitors?

Why are they clearing the cache?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> should work just fine or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Mouse Click the refresh button.

If you are looking to intelligently reload your resources automatically then that can be extremely difficult but here is a link for automatically refreshing CSS:

http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/

Not sure if there is anything for JS though :/

Answer (score 0):

Specific resources can be reloaded individually if you change the date and time on your files on the server. **"Clearing cache"** is not as easy as it should be. Instead of clearing cache on my browsers, I realized that "touching" the server files cached will actually change the date and time of the source file cached on the server (Tested on Edge, Chrome and Firefox) and most browsers will automatically download the most current fresh copy of whats on your server (code, graphics any multimedia too). I suggest you just copy the most current scripts on the server and **"do the touch thing"** solution before your program runs, so it will change the date of all your problem files to a most current date and time, then it downloads a fresh copy to your browser:

```
    <?php
      touch('/www/sample/file1.js');
      touch('/www/sample/file2.css');
    ?>
```

then ... the rest of your program...

It took me some time to resolve this issue (as many browsers act differently to different commands, but they all check time of files and compare to your downloaded copy in your browser, if different date and time, will do the refresh), If you can't go the supposed right way, there is always another usable and better solution to it. Best Regards and happy camping. By the way touch(); or alternatives work in many programming languages inclusive in javascript bash sh php and you can include or call them in html.